# Debugging Firebase Cloud Functions using Stackdriver

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am following this doc to try to debug my firebase cloud function: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/debugging

First of all the 
The require line given in the doc was wrong so I changed it to this to make it compile:

```
require('@google-cloud/debug-agent').start();
```

Also after implementing this and deploying the functions using `firebase deploy --only functions` there is no code in stack drive debug view. Any idea how to make this work?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'll make sure to fix the Firebase docs + call this out.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Cloud Functions for Firebase do not share their code with Stackdriver automatically. You'll need to source your code via Github, Bitbucket, or a Google Cloud Source Repository.

While [debugging Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/emulator) please refer to our documentation. We'll make sure to note any differences between the environments.

Comment: Thanks! I added the code using github then was able to activate the breakpoint by adding a node to firebase db. Was wondering if I could step over and step in using the breakpoints? Is there a way to do faster debugging of cloud functions?

Comment: You cannot step over and in with stackdriver as it's a sampling mechanism. You could set multiple snapshot points though.

Comment: While not officially supported yet, the Google Cloud Functions Emulator will give you good debugging abilities. You should check it out on GitHub. We're working on a first class integration.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Love firebase so far, great job! :)

Comment: The link is returning a 404 now.

Comment: @JamesDaniels, does the Stackdriver debugger currently work at all with Firebase functions? I managed to upload my local source files, but it doesn't let me set snapshot points. Since the docs link you posted above is currently broken, it's a bit hard to tell what the current status is.